# Blocking MS Word (2019 Office Pro) from the Internet

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, privacy

I blocked every application in the entire Office directory structure, and MS Word can still access the internet.

I used the program fab.exe (Firewall App Blocker) to add all the apps in the directories to Windows Defender with a couple clicks, and confirmed the apps were added as blocked in Windows Defender. I disabled everything available in Word in privacy options and the trust center.  There is no block internet setting. (MS Office Pro 2019, with a personal account log-in).

I can still follow links in Word (they open in Edge), and I can still login to the Microsoft account (no Edge required) from Word.

So, how do I block Word from accessing the internet?

Comment: Why bother? If you're concerned about MS covert access to *Word*, either to get info or to push changes, just use an equivalent third-party tool, such as the *free* LibreOffice suite's Writer. If a third party app attempts internet access, it can be blocked with FFB (or alternative Folder Firewall Blocker, https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/folder_firewall_blocker.html).

Comment: Work requires Word...

Comment: This includes Excel and Word? If it does then you forget an executable, likely, solely responsible for the help function

Answer (score 0):

Access to both http://microsoft.com and http://windowsupdate.com websites is prohibited on the router.
Or modify the Hosts file under C:Windows\System32\driver\setc
add:
127.0.0.1 microsoft.com
127.0.0.1 windowsupdate.com

Comment: well, what if microsoft have a bunch of IP addresses.. and microsoft.com only transltes to one of them.

Comment: Microsoft Windows ignores the *hosts* file for some of its own addresses:  https://petri.com/windows-10-ignoring-hosts-file-specific-name-resolution/ . such as *office.microsoft.com*. I.E., it would likely take an external device, not using Windows, to block those addresses.